# Полная поддержка utf8mb4 в Qt для хранения Emoji в MySql таблице?

Tags: mysql, sql, unicode

**Суть проблемы:**

В Qt парсится файл, в котором есть Emoji символы.

После этого, данные записываются в MySql таблицу типа - InnoDB, в атрибут типа varchar.
После добавления в таблицу (да и в самом Qt при дебаге) часть Emoji, такие как:
https://emojipedia.org/drop-of-blood/

https://emojipedia.org/tooth/

- не отображаются

**Что уже делал:**

- *Создание таблицы с указанием кодировки атрибутов:*

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `"+tableName+

   "`(filed1 int not null AUTO_INCREMENT, filed2 varchar(30),

   filed3 varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,  

   filed4 varchar(300) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci,

   filed5 varchar(100),PRIMARY KEY(filed1),INDEX USING BTREE(filed1)"");
```

- *Установка кодировки для БД:*

```
ALTER DATABASE <имя моей базы> CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

- *Установка кодировки в Qt:*

  `QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));`

Мне подсказали, что:

> mysql-клиенты, кстати, тоже должны использовать кодировку utf8mb4,
> иначе на перекодировании туда-сюда emoji тоже потеряются

Отсюда, у меня возникло два вопроса:

1. Судя по сообщениям этой темы https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25727970/pasting-emoji-in-qt-qtextedit/25732050#25732050 и по данным отладчика - qt захватывает эмодзи в виде escape последовательностей 55358, 56759, но просто не отображает (мне собственно, этого и не надо в редакторе), но если символы присутствуют в строке, почему в таблицу они все равно пишутся некорректно?
2. https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-60039?focusedCommentId=358330&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-358330
   -    As you know utf8mb4 is a MySQL define and not a real codec.

- тогда, как mysql-клиенты могут его использовать?

Еще, видел вариант, что после подключения к БД - необходимо первым запросом выполнить:

```
SET NAMES ("имя кодировки")
```

**Краткая суть вопроса:**

Как, работая с Qt, как с MySql клиентом, добиться полной поддержки Emoji символов, при записи в таблицу?

Comment: Что конкретно вы подразумеваете под поддержкой? Любой юникодный varchar может хранить любые юникодные символы, даже несуществующие.

Comment: Мне необходимо, что бы в строке хранился текст, содержащий Emoji, например:

https://emojipedia.org/drop-of-blood/

https://emojipedia.org/tooth/

Comment: Если у вас сейчас в базе кодировка utf8, то её нужно сменить на utf8mb4, и версии юникода тут ни при чём

Comment: Понял,спасибо. Не могли бы Вы оформить коментарий, как ответ на вопрос - отмечу его как правильный.

Comment: mysql-клиенты, кстати, тоже должны использовать кодировку utf8mb4, иначе на перекодировании туда-сюда emoji тоже потеряются

Comment: @andreymal, я работаю с  qt  и судя по сообщениям этой темы
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25727970/pasting-emoji-in-qt-qtextedit/25732050#25732050

и по данным отладчика  - qt захватывает эмодзи в виде escape последовательностей 55358, 56759, но просто не отображает (мне собственно, этого и не надо в редакторе), но если символы присутствуют в строке, почему в таблицу они все равно пишутся некорректно?

Comment: Выставил кодировку в qt
'    QTextCodec::setCodecForLocale(QTextCodec::codecForName("UTF-8"));'

Comment: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-60039?focusedCommentId=358330&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-358330
As you know utf8mb4 is a MySQL define and not a real codec. - тогда, как mysql-клиенты могут его использовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обеспечить полную поддержку символов так и не получилось, пришлось удалять часть эмодзи из строки. Тема про удаление - здесь:

[Удалить Emojii символ из строки в Qt?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1149547/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-emojii-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-qt/1150621#1150621)

Коротко:

> для удаления симолов эмодзи, необходимо воспользоваться статическим
> методом `QString::fromWCharArray()` - куда передать сурогатные пары

> `QString tmpStr=QString::fromWCharArray(L"\xD83E\xDDB7");`
> `myStr.remove(tmpStr);`