# Удалить Emojii символ из строки в Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, unicode

Есть эмодзи https://emojipedia.org/tooth/ - необхлдимо удалить его из строки.

Юникод брал отсюда: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f9b7/index.htm

Варианты:

> C/C++/Java source code    "\uD83E\uDDB7"

```
if (d->at(k).contains(u8"\\uD83E\\uDDB7")) 




if (d->at(k).contains(QString::fromUtf8(QByteArray("f09fa6b7"))))
```

Оба варианта не срабатывают.

Причем, при выводе Qdebug()  -символ выводится как `U0001F9B7`
судя по https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f9b7/index.htm - это

> Python source code u"\U0001F9B7"

Вариант:

```
(*d)[k]=(*d)[k].remove("\\U0001F9B7");
```

- так же не срабатывает.

Небольшое уточнение:

В Qt, при отладке данный эмодзи отображается как два символа ***55358(0xd83e)*** и ***56759 (0xdbd7)***, как и здесь:

http://www.mauvecloud.net/charsets/CharCodeFinder.html
(для проверки - )

причем, проверки на эти два символа:

`if (d->at(k).contains("0xd83e"))`  и  `if (d->at(k).contains("0xdbd7"))` - как раз, наоборот срабатывают, **но**

```
const_cast<QString*>(&d->at(k))->remove("\0xd83e");
const_cast<QString*>(&d->at(k))->remove("\0xdbd7");
```

- не дают эффекта.

**Основной вопрос:**

Прошу подсказать, как удалить данный символ и ему подомные(эмодзи)

**Дополнительный вопрос:**
Так же, что можно почитать про вопросы связанные с кодировкой и ее форматами.

**UPD:
Эти варианты НЕ работают.**

```
                        (*d)[k]=  (*d)[k].replace("\\55358","");
                        (*d)[k]=  (*d)[k].replace("\\56759","");
                        (*d)[k]=  (*d)[k].replace("\\154076","");
                        (*d)[k]=  (*d)[k].replace("\\156667","");

                        (*d)[k]=  (*d)[k].replace("\\0xdbd7","");
                        (*d)[k]=  (*d)[k].replace("\\56759","");

                        (*d)[k]=  (*d)[k].remove("\\55358");
                        (*d)[k]=  (*d)[k].remove("\\56759");
                        (*d)[k]=  (*d)[k].remove("\\154076");
                        (*d)[k]=  (*d)[k].remove("\\156667");

                        (*d)[k]=  (*d)[k].remove("\\0xdbd7");
                        (*d)[k]=  (*d)[k].remove("\\56759");
                        (*d)[k]=(*d)[k].remove("\\U0001F9B7");
            (*d)[k]= (*d)[k].remove(QRegularExpression("[\\x{1F600}-\\x{1F7FF}]+"));
                        (*d)[k]=(*d)[k].remove(QRegExp("(\\\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})"));
            (*d)[k]=(*d)[k].remove(QRegExp("\\\\[0-9]{5,}"));

                        (*d)[k]=   (*d)[k].remove("");
                        QRegularExpression numberRegularExpression("\\\\[0-9]{5}"); 
            //или  numberRegularExpression("[\\x{1F600}-\\x{1F7FF}]+")
            //или  numberRegularExpression("(\\\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4})")
```

Сначала попробовал вытянуть ESC-послдовательности, а уже потом - хотел инвертировать и вытянуять, все остальное но hasNext - не срабатывает

```
                        QRegularExpressionMatchIterator i = numberRegularExpression.globalMatch( (*d)[k]);

                        //find template matches
                        // numberRegExp.indexIn(tmpNumber);
                        //get coincidences
                        QStringList capturedData;//=numberRegExp.capturedTexts();

                        while (i.hasNext()) {
                            QRegularExpressionMatch match = i.next();
                            QString word = match.captured(1);
                            capturedData << word;
                        }
                        insertDataQuery.bindValue(columns.at(k),d->at
```

так же, **не** помогли варианты из этой темы на английском SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12807176/php-writing-a-simple-removeemoji-function/57744278#57744278

> It's a simple regex but supports it all!
>
> `$re = '/[ (\x{1F600}-\x{1F64F})| (\x{2700}-\x{27BF})|`
> `(\x{1F680}-\x{1F6FF})| (\x{24C2}-\x{1F251})| (\x{1F30D}-\x{1F567})|`
> `(\x{1F900}-\x{1F9FF})| (\x{1F300}-\x{1F5FF}) ]/mu';`

Comment: Вот из такой строки `QString s = "sdfsdfsdf\\uD83E\\uDDB7sdfsdfsdf";` все нормально удаляется  `s.remove("\\uD83E\\uDDB7");`

Comment: Если у вас массив байт в который символ выглядит так `d83edbd7` то искать и удалять надо `.contains("d83edbd7") `, то есть без  префикса`0x`. Как выглядит исходная строка, массив байт?

Comment: нет, просто обычная строка.

"\154075\some text data\154076\156667 some text data\154075\156150\154074\157773\20015⚕️ some text data\154075\156232 some text data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получилось удалить символы. Суть в том, что Qt почему-то не воспринимает симол, если пытаться удалить или заменить его, обращаясь, как `U0001F9B7`, даже, если символ там точно присутствует и выводится в таком формате в консоль, через `qDebug()`.

Для удаления симолов эмодзи, необходимо воспользоваться статическим методом `QString::fromWCharArray()` - куда передать сурогатные пары

(как раз те, ккоторые видны в отладчике как **55358(0xd83e) и 56759 (0xdbd7)** - в моем случае, для данного эмодзи).

Метод будет выглядеть так:

```
QString::fromWCharArray(L"\xD83E\xDDB7");
```

и, он как это не странно вернет ту же строку - `U0001F9B7`, но вот ее, почему-то, Qt уже прекрасно удаляет:

```
QString tmpStr=QString::fromWCharArray(L"\xD83E\xDDB7");
myStr.remove(tmpStr);
```

**В поисках ответа мне помогли:**

- Эта тема на английском SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30247319/how-do-you-use-unicode-in-qt

(на всякий случай, продублирую сюда текст ответа, т.к на SO уж очень не любят ссылки на другие ответы, но оставляю ссылку, что бы можно было поблагадорить автора оригинального ответа)

> You already know the answer - specify it as a proper UTF-16 string.
>
> Unicode codepoints above U+FFFF are represented in UTF-16 using a
> surrogate pair, which is two 16bit codeunits acting together to
> represent the full Unicode codepoint value. For U+1F50E, the surrogate
> pair is U+D83D U+DD0E.
>
> In Qt, a UTF-16 codeunit is represented as a QChar, so you need two
> QChar values, eg:
>
> `edit.setText(QString::fromWCharArray(L"\xD83D\xDD0E"));`
>
> or:
>
> `edit.setText(QString::fromStdWString(L"\xD83D\xDD0E"));`
>
> Assuming a platform where sizeof(wchar_t) is 2 and not 4.
>
> In your example, you tried using `QString::fromUtf8()`, but you gave it
> an invalid UTF-8 string. For U+1F50E, it should have looked like this
> instead:
>
> `edit.setText(QString::fromUtf8("\xF0\x9F\x94\x8E"));`
>
> You can also use `QString::fromUcs4()` instead:
>
> `uint cp = 0x1F50E; edit.setText(QString::fromUcs4(&cp, 1));`

- Данный калькулятор для вычисления юникода по суррогатным парам и
  наоборот:

http://www.russellcottrell.com/greek/utilities/SurrogatePairCalculator.htm